# Power bank DIY Build (Regarding protection circuits)

Tags: power-supply, power, batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion

I have been toying with the idea of making a power bank, as I have a few old laptop batteries lying around which are still working well. I plan to use these components:

- Constant-current lithium charger with under-voltage and over-voltage protection
- Battery Management System
- CC/CV 5v Converter

Would it be advisable to use these components? I realised that most guides and power bank circuits lack a lot of these protection features. I'm not sure if it's necessary, as it will bring the efficiency down. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe i am just lucky but most very cheap powerbank circuits you can buy have phenomenal undervolt, overvolt, charge/discharge and the important one, **short circuit protection**

Answer (score -1):

If you just have parallel cells i.e the batteries will just be 3.7V, then you can combine different capacity cells without a problem.

When you series cells, they should have the same capacity - and random mix of old batteries may not. Your BMS likely has a limited ability to balance different cells on charge. On discharge the low capacity bank gets over discharged.

But you can test this out by monitoring the charge and discharge for a test and see if they are balanced. If they all come from the same packs they might be. However, some laptop batteries fail because a cell has a lower capacity.